# Проблема при запуске tmux в контейнере Docker

Tags: linux, debian, docker, containers, tmux

Запускаю процесс в окне tmux из контейнера: tmux new -s paper "java -jar paper.jar"

Но tmux выдает ошибку: open terminal failed: not a terminal

Comment: `$ docker -t ..`

Comment: только мне не понятно, зачем tmux запускать в докере...

Comment: @KoVadim в докере всё можно запускать ... например настроен контейнер на сервере сборочная-среда-Васи, он туда заходит, и одновременно разные скрипты пускает.

Comment: допустим. Но я бы до такого никогда бы не додумался.

Comment: Вот тут я уже не понял. Почему Вася не может эти контейнеры у себя на машине поднять?